# I cant start an activity using applicationContext and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity

Hi i am trying to create an uncaught exception handler in android studio but when i try to start the activity it does nothing

This is the class:

```
public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException ( @NonNull Thread t, @NonNull Throwable e ) {
        BaseActivity.applicationContext.startActivity( new Intent().setClass( BaseActivity.applicationContext, ExceptionHandler.class )
                .putExtra( "ex", e )
                .setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ));
    }
}
```

This is the ExceptionHandler class:

```
public class ExceptionHandler extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.exception_screen );
        Throwable e = (Exception) getIntent().getExtras().get( "ex" );
        Main.showAlert( this, "An exception occurred", e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

This is the BaseActivity class:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Context applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler( new UncaughtExceptionHandler() );
        int i = 2 / 0; // to test the exception handler
    }
}
```

it calls the uncaughtException method but doesnt start the ExceptionHandler activity class

I defined the activity in the manifest

Comment: is your applicationContext is  null or not when unCaughtException method is getting called ?

Comment: @AshutoshOjha it isnt null

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is used for questions/issues regarding the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the relevant part of your manifest.